# Installing Laravel Spark issue

Tags: laravel, xampp, installation, laravel-spark

I am trying to install Laravel Spark following the Spark installation procedure here: https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation

I can get the packages and dependencies to install correctly ad without any issues using: spark new sparkapp --team-billing

however when I serve the page (on xampp) and go to the registration page the page does not render properly. What I see is a semi-processed template and with no css and javascript as below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It looks you haven't run gulp, which will compile the css and javascript into files that will then be applied to your webpage. Notice halfway down the installation docs for Spark, it says:

> Note: Once Spark has been installed, don't forget to run npm install,
>   gulp, and php artisan migrate.

If you have tried running gulp, then make sure it doesn't result in an error. I've been having the same error and it's because gulp is not installing correctly.